# Odd Powershell Substring/Replace Issue Occurring

Tags: powershell, replace, substring

I have to update a file with one line every day in three different sections of the line.

The line in the file on January 15th before the update was as follows:

XXXXXX      **0113**011335*2021013115126*XXXX     200500**0113**   XXX XXX       XXX       I

So, the line is divided by spaces into 7 segments. I have to update the **first 4 characters of the second segment with MMDD<-1>**, the *13 characters prior to the XXXX in the second segment with YYYYJJJHHMMSS<-1>* and then the **last four digits of the third segment with MMDD<-1>**

Here is my code:

```
#get the year minuse 1 day, get the day of the year minuse 1 day, get the current time 
$yeardayofyeartime = (get-date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy") + (get-date).AddDays(-1).dayofyear.ToString("000") + (get-date).ToString("HHmmss")
Add-Content -Path $logpath -Value "The year, Julian date, and time is:"
Add-Content -Path $logpath -Value $yeardayofyeartime

#get the current month and day minus 1
$monthday = (get-date).AddDays(-1).ToString("MMdd")
Add-Content -Path $logpath -Value "The month and the day is: $monthday."
Add-Content -Path $logpath -Value $monthday

$Content = Get-Content $source
Add-Content -Path $logpath -Value "Content in the file before update is:"
Add-Content -Path $logpath -Value $Content

$Content.Replace($Content.Substring(12, 4), $monthday).Replace($Content.Substring(22, 13), $yeardayofyeartime).Replace($Content.Substring(51, 4), $monthday) | Out-File -encoding ASCII $source

Add-Content -Path $logpath -Value "Content in the file after update:"
Get-Content $source | Add-Content -Path $logpath

Add-Content -Path $logpath -Value "*********************************************************************************************************"
    
exit 0
```

The odd thing is that it's also updating **16,4 with MMDD<-1>** and I don't know why. Here's what I've created a log to monitor these changes and here's what I found. These logs start on the 15th.

The year, Julian date, and time is:
2021014060002
The month and the day is: 0114.
0114
Content in the file before update is:
XXXXXX      0113**0113**352021013115126XXXX      2005000113   XXX XXX       XXX       I
Content in the after update:
XXXXXX      0114**0114**352021014060002XXXX      2005000114   XXX XXX       XXX       I

---

The year, Julian date, and time is:
2021015060002
The month and the day is: 0115.
0115
Content in the file before update is:
XXXXXX      0114**0114**352021014060002XXXX      2005000114   XXX XXX       XXX       I
Content in the after update:
XXXXXX      0115**0115**352021015060002XXXX      2005000115   XXX XXX       XXX       I

---

The year, Julian date, and time is:
2021016060002
The month and the day is: 0116.
0116
Content in the file before update is:
XXXXXX      0115**0115**352021015060002XXXX      2005000115   XXX XXX       XXX       I
Content in the after update:
XXXXXX      0116**0116**352021016060002XXXX      2005000116   XXX XXX       XXX       I

---

The year, Julian date, and time is:
2021017060002
The month and the day is: 0117.
0117
Content in the file before update is:
XXXXXX      0116**0116**352021016060002XXXX      2005000116   XXX XXX       XXX       I
Content in the after update:
XXXXXX      0117**0117**352021017060002XXXX      2005000117   XXX XXX       XXX       I

---

The year, Julian date, and time is:
2021018060002
The month and the day is: 0118.
0118
Content in the file before update is:
XXXXXX      0117**0117**352021017060002XXXX      2005000117   XXX XXX       XXX       I
Content in the after update:
XXXXXX      0118**0118**352021018060002XXXX      2005000118   XXX XXX       XXX       I

---

The year, Julian date, and time is:
2021019060002
The month and the day is: 0119.
0119
Content in the file before update is:
XXXXXX      0118**0118**352021018060002XXXX      2005000118   XXX XXX       XXX       I
Content in the after update:
XXXXXX      0119**0119**352021019060002XXXX      2005000119   XXX XXX       XXX       I

---

The year, Julian date, and time is:
2021020060002
The month and the day is: 0120.
0120
Content in the file before update is:
XXXXXX      0119**0119**352021019060002XXXX      2005000119   XXX XXX       XXX       I
Content in the after update:
XXXXXX      0120**0120**352021020060002XXXX      2005000120   XXX XXX       XXX       I

---

Any ideas why this part is updating as well?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use the repeated `.Replace()` methods here, but rather split the string into segments and do the replacements on each segment. Then rejoin these to form the new content:

```
$segments = $content -split ' '
# split the second segment into 4 parts
$subs = $segments[1] -split '^(\d{4})(\d{6})(\d{13})(.*)' -ne ''
$subs[0] = $monthday
$subs[2] = $yeardayofyeartime
# rejoin the sub parts to form the new $segment[1]
$segments[1] = $subs -join ''

# replace the third segment
# or use $segments[2] = $segments[2] -replace '(.*)\d{4}$', "`$1$monthday"
$segments[2] = $segments[2].Substring(0,6) + $monthday

# rejoin the updated segments to form the new content line
$content = $segments -join ' '
```

---

To explain what [@g.sulman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5039142/g-sulman) asked in his comment:
*"What does `-ne ''` do on the `$subs = ...` line"*

PowerShell's `-split` operator has a gotcha:

When the input string to splits **starts** (and in this case also **ends**) in a regex match, `-split` treats the first and last element of the split to be an empty string.

Demo:

```
$subs = '01130113352021013115126XXXX' -split '^(\d{4})(\d{6})(\d{13})(.*)'
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $subs.Count; $i++) {
    '{0}: {1}' -f $i, $subs[$i]
}
```

Result:

```
0: 
1: 0113
2: 011335
3: 2021013115126
4: XXXX
5:
```

By passing the resulting array to `-ne ''`, we filter out these empty strings:

```
$subs = '01130113352021013115126XXXX' -split '^(\d{4})(\d{6})(\d{13})(.*)' -ne ''
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $subs.Count; $i++) {
    '{0}: {1}' -f $i, $subs[$i]
}
```

Result:

```
0: 0113
1: 011335
2: 2021013115126
3: XXXX
```

Comment: What does `-ne '` on the `$subs = ..` line do?

Comment: @g.sulman That is needed to ensure the array returned by `-split` does not contain empty elements. Please see my edit where I explain.